# Calling a custom action within a nested resource (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to call a custom controller action **shuffle** for a resource that is nested within another resource. I can't seem to get the method call right.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :templates do
  resources :items
end

match "/templates/:template_id/items/shuffle" => "items#shuffle"
```

I have a link in my items#index view:

`<%= link_to 'Shuffle', shuffle_template_items_path(@template) %>`

When I click on the link, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `shuffle_template_items_path' for #<#<Class:0x42577c8>:0x3e77578>
```

I have also tried `<%= link_to 'Shuffle', template_items_shuffle_path(@template) %>` and that did not work.

How do I correctly call this custom action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
resources :templates do
  resources :items do
    get :shuffle, :on => :collection
  end
end
```

Comment: you also can add :as => :suffle_template_items after the collection..this would be the nicest way in my opinion..

Comment: It correctly shows `shuffle_template_items` in `rake routes` but I'm still getting the same error message: `undefined method 'shuffle_template_items'`. I tried restarting the server and that didn't help either. My link is `<%= link_to 'Shuffle', shuffle_template_items(@template) %>`

Comment: Oops, forget to include `path` at the end of it! `shuffle_template_items_path(@template)` worked!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want your custom action to have a name, you need to provide it:

```
match "/templates/:template_id/items/shuffle" => "items#shuffle", :as => :suffle_template_items
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to write shuffle is in collection as per the documentation of [Rails Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions):

So it would looks like this:

```
  resources :templates do
    resources :items do
      collection do
        get :shuffle
      end
    end
  end
```

when you try `rake routes` you will find `shuffle_template_items GET    /templates/:template_id/items/shuffle(.:format)  items#shuffle`.

Comment: I've never heard of `collection` in rails.. I'll have to look into that. Thank you.